# Electronic Deadbolt for Door

Tags: arduino

I am not sure "deadbolt" is the correct term for what I am looking for. I am searching for the metal piece on the side of doors that extends to lock it, but one that can be controlled electronically (with Arduino).

The thing on the right of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyt6pUXYY6A) is exactly what I want, but I can't seem to find anything like it.

Does anyone know where I could find one of these, or at least what this would be called?

I am also open to other setups to lock a door, but the part I described above is preferable. It doesn't need to be very secure or anything; I mostly just want to make use of an RFID scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally found the answer to my own question. What I am looking for suddenly happened to appear in my Amazon recommendations (even though I haven't searched for anything like this on Amazon), and found you can find a lot of electric door locks by searching "open frame type solenoid" including [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AOCAETQ), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the most success with installing an actual non-electronic deadbolt bought at a hardware store such as Home Depot (if one is not already installed), such as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vmOj4DII8I

And then hooking up a servo motor controlled by an arduino (or similar) attached an RFID scanner to lock and unlock the deadbolt.  One possible bonus is that your servo and arduino + RFID setup will be portable to other doors.  One retail example is the Kevo Convert by Kwikset, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YY0_IrvXGE

Comment: I already found what I was looking for, however this may be a better solution. This is especially because if I lose power on the electronic one it will immediately lock (they need power to retract the deadlock and I don't know if I constantly want to rely on my setup being on and working).

Comment: Any ideas on how this setup would work specifically? Aside from installing the regular deadlock what would be the best method to control it with a servo?  (ex. Use some sort of string or other material to pull the knob with the servo or modify the deadlock in some way?)